# CSS when inline-block elements line-break, parent wrapper does not fit new width

Tags: html, css

How do you get an `inline-block` element to fit its content width, if the content line-breaks because of screen width?

```
<!-- parent inline-block -->
<div style='display: inline-block;'>
    <div style='display: inline-block; width:200px;'></div>
    <!--
        If this child line breaks, 
        two 200px wide blocks are stacked vertically.
        That should make the parent width 200px,
        but the parent stays much wider than that
    -->
    <div style='display: inline-block; width:200px;'></div>
</div>
```

I can't think of how to phrase the question so it sounds easy, but I put together a simple **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wcx1c9tu/1/)** illustrating.

```css
#wide {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
#narrow {
  position: relative;
  width: 175px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}
.wrap {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  margin: auto;
}
.inlineblock {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  background: red;
  min-width: 100px;
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<section id='wide'>
  <div class='wrap'>
    <div class='inlineblock'></div>
    <div class='inlineblock'></div>
  </div>
</section>
<p>
  When the red inline-blocks are forced to line break, how do you make a parent with display:inline-block (the green border) snap to fit? How do you get rid of all the extra horiztonal space in the lower green bordered div?
</p>
<section id='narrow'>
  <div class='wrap'>
    <div class='inlineblock'></div>
    <div class='inlineblock'></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: You can't...that's not how the line box model works.

Comment: You may want to set the parent div width to 200px as well?

Comment: With white-space:preline I can get rid of the extra width space, but it forces the inline-block elements to line break from the start. There's no wway to only do preline white-space on linebreak?

Comment: I think you should search for CSS Flex it probably is what you need..

Comment: @miguelmpn Nope...not even flexbox can do that.

Comment: related: [Make container shrink-to-fit child elements as they wrap](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37406353/3597276)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can't. By default, `inline-block` elements have a [shrink-to-fit width](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width):

> The shrink-to-fit width is:
>   `min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)`.

Then,

- When `preferred minimum width <= preferred width <= available width`, the width will be the `preferred width`, as you desire.
- When `available width <= preferred minimum width <= preferred width`, the width will be the `preferred minimum width`, as you desire.
- When `preferred minimum width <= available width <= preferred width`, the width will be the `available width`, even if you don't like it.

If you really don't want this, I guess you could add a `resize` event listener with JS, and set the desired width manually.

Comment: @Paulie_D Yes, floats also use the shrink-to-fit width (in fact it's defined for them). And basically all atomic inline-level boxes do the same.

Comment: Thanks...that was my understanding too. Odd that this hasn't been solved yet...seems to be a common design request.

Comment: @Paulie_D Maybe it's intentional, to avoid abrupt changes of the width and possible circular definitions. But it would be nice to have this in non-problematic cases.

Comment: @Paulie_D BTW, flex items use max-content instead of fit-content/shrink-to-fit. I have self-answered [Should flex item overflow the flex container instead of breaking lines?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35005024/1529630) to explain this.

Comment: I was wondering if in 2024, there a was a solution for this problem? The CSS grid solution doesn't work when it comes the dynamic text...

Answer (score 21):

`inline-block` elements can't achieve this layout - as demonstrated by @Oriol - but,

## CSS Grid can achieve this layout.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  display: inline-grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 100px);
  min-width: 50vw;
  
  /* decorative properties */
  grid-gap: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  border: 5px solid salmon;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* center the grid */ 
  position: relative;
  left: 50vw;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
li {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
  <li>17</li>
  <li>18</li>
  <li>19</li>
  <li>20</li>
  <li>21</li>
  <li>22</li>
</ul>
```

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/ERajZr) (Be sure to resize)

Basically the relevant code boils down to this:

```css
ul {
  display: inline-grid; /* (1) */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 100px); /* 100px = column width - (2) */
  min-width: 50vw; /* or any user-defined min-width (3) */
}
```

1. Make the container element an inline-grid container. This will cause the grid to 'shrink-wrap' its contents - so that the grid width will never be wider than it's contents.
2. Set the grid with a responsive layout (The `auto-fill` / `auto-fit` value is used for responsive layouts). If there is no room in a row to fit the next item - it wraps to the next row.

When a responsive layout is used together with an inline-grid - the grid width will equal the width of one item of the grid. (when no width/min-width is explicitly set - [like this](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/PazeVO))

3. Set the container with a min-width which represents (at most - one partial item less than) the desired **maximum width** for the container.

So if the given min-width exactly fits in a certain number of items - that means that this will also be the **maximum** width of the grid because the next item will wrap.

If however the min-width doesn't exactly correspond to the width of 'n' items in that it also fits in part of the n+1th item - in this case the grid will slightly expand to exactly fit the n+1th item - with the n+2th item wrapping to the next row.

Comment: If we wanted to fit as many `100px` columns as would fit in the parent container, could we use `min-width: calc(100% - 100px);`

Comment: Unfortunately for me this doesn't appear to be applicable to items having a dynamic width within the container, for instance with text, and also with a dynamic maximum width. Thought if I wrapped every word in a span there may be some way of using this.

Comment: Yeah, I guess this doesn't work well with dynamically sized (width-wise) content, since A) You have a grid structure and B) you'll somehow need to specify the grid-columns width.

Comment: When I try to modify this with `max-width:870px;min-width:320px` (with the aim of it trying to show as many columns as possible, up to 8 (8 * 100px + 7 * 10px gap), it doesn't shrink down.  I can make the window 600px wide and it'll still be 870px wide.  What am I doing wrong?