# Should flex item overflow the flex container instead of breaking lines?

Tags: css, flexbox, language-lawyer

I have this layout:

- A [row](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-direction-row) [flex container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers) with a [definite size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#definite), e.g. `width: 175px`
- A [flex item](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)

  - With an in[definite](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#definite) [`flex-basis`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property), e.g. [`flex-basis: content`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#content)
  - Which is inflexible, e.g. [`flex: none`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-none).
  - Whose [`max-content` size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#max-content) is larger than the [available space](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#available)
  - Whose [`min-content` size](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#min-content) is smaller than the [available space](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#available)

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 175px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: none;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  margin: 3px;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As expected, Firefox breaks lines inside the flex item and sets its width to the available space.

[image]

However, Chrome doesn't break lines and thus the flex item overflows the flex container:

[image]

Who is right? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what happens:

1. The [Line Length Determination](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#line-sizing) algorithm determines that the [flex base size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-base-size) of the flex item is its [`max-content`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-sizing-3/#max-content)

   > Size the item into the [available space](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing-3/#available) using its used [flex
   >   basis](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis) in place of its [main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size), treating a value of
   >   `content` as [`max-content`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-sizing-3/#valdef-width-max-content). [...] The [flex base size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-base-size) is
   >   the item’s resulting [main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size).
2. Since there are no min nor max size constraints, the [hypothetical main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#hypothetical-main-size) of the flex item is the same value

   > The [hypothetical main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#hypothetical-main-size) is the item’s [flex base size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-base-size)
   >   clamped according to its min and max main size properties.
3. The [Resolving Flexible Lengths](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#resolve-flexible-lengths) algorithm freezes the inflexible flex item and sets its [target main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#target-main-size) to its [hypothetical main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#hypothetical-main-size)

   > Size inflexible items. Freeze, setting its target main size to its
   >   [hypothetical main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#hypothetical-main-size) any item that has a flex factor of zero
4. Finally, the [main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size) is that value too:

   > Set each item’s used [main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#main-size) to its [target main size](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#target-main-size).

Therefore, your flex item should be sized as if it had `flex-basis: max-content`. Chrome, Edge and IE do it correctly.

Instead, Firefox seems to size as if it had `flex-basis: fit-content`. IMO this is more reasonable, but it's not standard. [Bug 876985](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=876985) should fix this.

Meanwhile, to achieve the standard behavior on Firefox you can use

```css
flex-basis: -moz-max-content;
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 175px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: none;
  flex-basis: -moz-max-content;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  margin: 3px;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Instead, if you want Firefox's behavior on other browsers, it's not that easy.

Chrome doesn't support `fit-content` on `flex-basis`, but it does on `width` (prefixed)

```css
flex-basis: auto;
width: -webkit-fit-content;
width: fit-content;
```

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 175px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: none;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  margin: 3px;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, IE/Edge doesn't support `fit-content` anywhere. But a max constraint should work on all browsers

```css
max-width: 100%;
box-sizing: border-box; /* Include paddings and borders */
```

Note the constraint won't include margins, so you may need to correct the percentage using `calc`, e.g. `max-width: calc(100% - 6px)`.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 175px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.flex-item {
  flex: none;
  max-width: calc(100% - 6px);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 3px solid blue;
  margin: 3px;
}
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```