# How to remove these extra spaces from a p element?

Tags: css

This is the code that demonstrates the case:

#### HTML

```html
<div class="skill-cat">
<p class="skill-cat-title">Others</p>
  <div class="skills">
    <p class="skill">Familiar with Mac and Windows operating systems</p>
    <p class="skill">Markdown markup language</p>
    <p class="skill">Lyx (LaTex typesetting application)</p>
    <p class="skill">many of Apple iWork and Microsoft Office applications</p>
    <p class="skill">video editing</p>
    <p class="skill">working with command-line interface</p>
    <p class="skill">research and self-learning</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.skill-cat-title {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 115%;
    margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.skills {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.skill {
    margin: 7px 7px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: gold;
}
```

You can view the code and its output on CodePen here: https://codepen.io/ammar_/pen/qXgvZg/

When the width of the viewport becomes about `360px`, extra areas that don't contain text appear. I want to remove these areas.

The areas are shown in the following image inside red rectangles:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Basically, **NO**...that's not the way the line-box model works - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35005024/should-flex-item-overflow-the-flex-container-instead-of-breaking-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `<p>` tag, use `<span>` and use `<br>` tag for line break.
Also, need to set the `line-height` otherwise because of `padding` it gets overlapped.

```css
.skill-cat-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 115%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.skills {}

.skill {
  padding: 5px 5px;
  line-height: 25px;
  background-color: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-cat">
  <p class="skill-cat-title">Others</p>
  <div class="skills">
    <span class="skill">Familiar with Mac and Windows operating systems</span><br/><br/>

    <span class="skill">Markdown markup language</span><br/><br/>
    <span class="skill">Lyx (LaTex typesetting application)</span><br/><br/>
    <span class="skill">many of Apple iWork and Microsoft Office applications</span><br/><br/>
    <span class="skill">video editing</span><br/><br/>
    <span class="skill">working with command-line interface</span><br/><br/>
    <span class="skill">research and self-learning</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works! But 1. Why did you choose `line-height` to be `25px`; how did you calculate it?  2. Why doesn't this solution work when `flexbox` is enabled?

Comment: 1. `by default font size in browser` is **16px** and here we have **5px** `padding top and bottom`, so it calculated **26px**, so I just set it to 25px. 

2. **`Flex boxes`** has the ability to alter its items' width and height to fit in the available space, so it won't work in your case.

Answer (score 3):

Try `text-align: justify`. That way, wrapped lines in paragraphs will be stretched horizontally to the right edge.

```css
.skill-cat {
  width: 360px; /* added to demonstrate wrapping */
}

.skill-cat-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 115%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.skills {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.skill {
  margin: 7px 7px;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: gold;
  text-align: justify;
}
```

```html
<div class="skill-cat">
  <p class="skill-cat-title">Others</p>
  <div class="skills">
    <p class="skill">Familiar with Mac and Windows operating systems</p>
    <p class="skill">Markdown markup language</p>
    <p class="skill">Lyx (LaTex typesetting application)</p>
    <p class="skill">many of Apple iWork and Microsoft Office applications</p>
    <p class="skill">video editing</p>
    <p class="skill">working with command-line interface</p>
    <p class="skill">research and self-learning</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good, but the words appear over-spaced. I am looking to remove those extra spaces completely.

Comment: @ammarx as a matter of fact you *can't* unless you either opt for `text-align: justify` or set a `word-break` behavior... Another is you can use *ellipsis* if you are keeping the text in a single line...

Comment: My other idea is to add `<br>` tags and make them display only on certain viewport widths.

Comment: @juzraai This might actually be the most effective solution in my opinion, although it requires more configurations.

Comment: Indeed, that would require a lot of markup and would be hard to maintain. Instead you can try @user2's answer, that looks promising.

Answer (score 2):

```
.skill {
    margin: 7px 7px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: gold;
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Try to add `word-break: break-all`

Comment: This does remove the extra spaces, but it makes the text appear ugly. Breaking words without hyphens is a bad idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

If the width is significiant in your case just use media queries

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 360px)
{
  .skills p
  {
    word-break: break-all;
  }
```

}

This will allow you to trigger specified behavior in the desired way!

EDIT:

You can always try to align text using properties on containers like adding `width: 80%;` to above code, You can also combine those with hints from other answers.