# Adjust div width to content with JS

Tags: html, css

Setting `display: inline-block` should make the surrounding div not larger than its content: [How to make div not larger than its contents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450903/how-to-make-div-not-larger-than-its-contents)

However, when line-breaks are included it does not work ([jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nepcc85/))):

```
<style>
.container{
  border: solid;
  display: inline-block
}

.box{
  background-color: #08c;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<div class='container'>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

[image]

It is stated in [CSS when inline-block elements line-break, parent wrapper does not fit new width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width) that one can correct the width of the DIV with jQuery. How would you do it for this example?

**Answer** The question is marked as a duplicate, so I cant give an answer, but this worked for me ([jFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12vbg5b0/)):

```
<style>
.container{
  border: solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

.box{
  background-color: #08c;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
</style>

<script>
function adjust(){
// reset container width
$('.container').width('');
var x = $('.container').width();

  // size of box is 90px (50+20+20), so set width to the minimal width which  // is dividible by 90px
  x= x - (x % 90);
  $('.container').width(x);
}

$(document).ready(function(){

adjust();

$(window).resize(adjust);
});
</script>


<div class='container'>
<div class='box'></div><!--
--><div class='box'></div><!--
--><div class='box'></div><!--
--><div class='box'></div><!--
--><div class='box'></div><!--
--><div class='box'></div>
</div>
```

Also since the boxes are inline-elements, I needed to remove the whitespace, otherwise they don't fit in the div.

[image]

Comment: I am getting all the boxes in a single line and outline around them. That's expected right?

Comment: @Himanshu Yes, but if you make your window smaller and force a line break, you get a gap as in my image. How can I prevent this?

Comment: You can't...that's not the way the line box model works.

Comment: Your `div.container`has `text-align: left`.

Try to add `text-align: center;` for a better effect or maybe `text-align: justify;`

Comment: Add a `min-width` to the `container`, it will not shrink. And there is a `;` missing is `display` property of `container`.

Comment: @Paulie_D thank you for the link. I have edited my question, so that it is not a duplicate any longer.

Comment: When content of wrapper div is more than div width and partially moves to 2nd line, wrapper becomes 100% width even if it is inline-block.

Comment: It's still a duplicate and asking for a JS solution is off-topic unless you have tried to resolve this with your own code,

Answer (score 0):

Add min-width: 566px to your container:

[image: Add min-width]

Comment: Changing the window size can again lead to a gap. Also I would like to get  a solution that works if I change the width of the box elements.