# How to make html element wrap its content and shrink to fit afterwards?

Tags: html, css, browser, render

EDIT. The question is reworded as suggested by @Aziz in his comments. It was previously asking about achieving the same effect with `inline-block`, which seems impossible, see the answer to 
[CSS when inline-block elements line-break, parent wrapper does not fit new width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width). The new question asks how else this effect can be achieved, so it is *no more duplicate*.

I have a parent row container with two child columns. I want each of the children to wrap their text content and then shrink to fit their width **after** the wrapping.

The example below almost achieves this effect:

```css
.parent {
  display: inline-block;
}
.child {
  max-width: 180px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid thin;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
      I am child with loooong text.
  </div>
  <div class="child">
      I am child with loooong text.
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a Demo](http://jsbin.com/vicoxe/2/edit?html,css,output)

The only problem is that each child does not completely shrink to fit its content. There is clear white space gap on the right of the text inside each child.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/07m8039j/

Comment: @Aziz The same problem - does not shrink-to-fit for some width.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your desired effect, you just need to make sure that `.child` is a block element. that way it will occupy the parent's width and wrap the rest under it.

```css
.parent {
  border:1px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.child {
  border:1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  I shrink to content slightly longer
  <div class="child">
    incl.Child
  </div>
  but not enough!
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/021xqwo4/

Comment: `display: inline` achieves a different layout, it does not separately wrap the content inside each child. I actually want to wrap.

Comment: you want to wrap? what do you mean?

Comment: To wrap the content of each child element. I want them to appear as columns and to wrap into several lines their inside content, but still shrink-to-fit their content.

Comment: You mean like that https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/tftoqe7c/ but shrink the width to longest *sentence*?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Seems impossible with neither `inline-block` nor `float` ;(

Comment: Ok I suggest you reword the question because the duplicate isn't exactly what you need. Your question is really about: how to make inline-block child occupy container space and wrap elements after it - I will update my answer

Comment: Reworded now as suggested.