# Make div always have the width of its contents

Tags: html, css

I have a container `div` with a few elements inside, like so:

```
<div class="container">
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>four</p>
  <p>five</p>
  <p>six</p>
  <p>seven</p>
  <p>eight</p>
</div>
```

It looks like this:

[image: SS]

You can the that the `.container` div (in blue) extends to fill the whole width of the window. I would like it to always 'hug' the `p`'s inside, to always have the minimum `width` necessary.

I have accomplished by setting it to `display: inline-block`. Now it looks like
[image: SS2]

Here comes the problem. When I re-size the window so that one of the elements gets 'pushed' down to a second row, the `.container` div does not shrink to fit the new size of the elements. Instead, it stretches to the edge of the window.

[image: SS3]

How would I make the div fit its contents, even when re-sizing, so that it would look like so?

[image: SS4]

I have searched and searched, but could not find an answer to this problem.

JSFiddle **[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/z6hLt7wh/2/)**

Comment: Check out Flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Duplicate of [CSS when inline-block elements line-break, parent wrapper does not fit new width](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34995740/1529630). Not possible.

Answer (score 2):

That's not possible, so as close as possible, you can use `flexbox` for that

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap
}
.container p {
  background: pink;
  font-size: 40px;
  margin:10px 0
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>one</p>
  <p>two</p>
  <p>three</p>
  <p>four</p>
  <p>five</p>
  <p>six</p>
  <p>seven</p>
  <p>eight</p>
  <p>nine</p>
  <p>ten</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You are only justifying the items, not shrinking the container, which I don't think is possible.

Comment: @Oriol, Ya I don't think so too, but this what I remember to get as close as possible of what OP is trying to achieve