# Display inline-block on title tag

Tags: html, css

1. So i would like to add a border to a h3 tag.
2. This border needs to span the width of the longest part of the
   visible text and no futher.
3. Currently this border seems to span the entire width of the wrapping
   div.

Seems weird to me that adding display inline block to a h tag doesn't provide me with the results I was after.

```css
div {
  max-width: 180px;
}
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolar.....</h3>
</div>
```

EDIT: Seems that some of you don't get that the max-width is required.

This is how it sould line up.

[image]

Hmmm... Seems that a perfect solution isn't possible with CSS. But I've used @Muhammad Usman example and added `bottom: -120%;`and replaced the height and background with border properties. which works for 2 lines of text.

```css
div {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: dashed 1px grey;
}
h3 {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  position: relative;
}
h3::after {
  border-bottom: 4px solid green;
  bottom: -120%;
  content: "";
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolar</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolar set ammet Lorem ipsum dolar set ammet Lorem ipsum dolar set ammet Lorem ipsum dolar set ammet Lorem ipsum dolar set ammet</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So, if I understand, `max-width` is required and you want your border to be as long as the longest line in the title. And I guess this length is unknown, right?

Comment: Exactly @JordiNebot.

Comment: This is probably not possible with CSS in any dynamic form. That's not the way the line-box model works. - Related- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width

Comment: As I mentioned above...this is not possible. The inline-block heading is not shrink-wrapping how you think it is. The linked Q& A applies here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I thought I would update this question as no one else has found the answer.

It is possible when using flexbox, just wrap the title tag with a div and apply flex to it.

```css
div {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: dashed 1px grey;
}
div.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:row wrap;
  }
h3 {
  display: inline;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  border-bottom: 4px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
<h3>Lorem Ipsum <br>Dolar</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolar set ammet Lorem ipsum dolar set ammet Lorem ipsum dolar set ammet Lorem ipsum dolar set ammet Lorem ipsum dolar set ammet</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just erase the max-width and only use `display: inline-block`

```css
div {
  }
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  }
```

```html
<div>
<h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolar.....</h3>
 </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi So you think I've added a max-width to the wrapping div for fun?

Comment: There is no direct question. "This border needs to span the width of the longest part of the visible text" is what comes closest to a question and I gave you a solution for that.

Comment: if the max-width 180px is mandatory, you already have the answer in the question - ?

Comment: I don't that border stretches the full width of the containing div not the text. As per my question.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```css
div {
  max-width: 180px;
  width:111px;
}
h3 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 2px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolar.....</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Then line is stretching the width of the wrapping div. Not the longest part of the text.

Comment: You don't understand the problem.

Comment: sorry not understood. You want that border til dolar... ?

Comment: @dfsq may be..can you please explain?

Comment: You can't just hardcode `width:111px;` this should be automatic, because it changes depending on the text.

Answer (score 0):

Add Display:inline property for your "div"

```
 div {
        max-width: 180px;
        display: inline;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  max-width: 180px;
}

h3 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}


h3:before {
  position: absolute;
  background: green;
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -4px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum Dolar Lorem Ipsum Dolar gnhhjkui abc .....</h3>
</div>
```