# How to get a centered text in a box as small as possible

Tags: html, css

My problem is that when I use `text-align: center;` , my text is centered but the "p" element doesn't resize to fit the text.

In the example below, we can see that the "p" element is much larger thant the text itself, I would like it to fit perfectly the text, because I want the text to be against the green borders (but still centered in its "p").

How could I do that ?

```css
#container {
  width: 270px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px green solid;
}

div {
  border: 2px black solid;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <p>Small text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>This is another small paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I want the text to be against the red borders.` Is it just me or isn't there anything red? Do you mean the black borders?

Comment: well you cannot ... i will find the questions that will explain why

Comment: Sorry, I changed the color. I want the text to be against the green borders.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406353/make-container-shrink-to-fit-child-elements-as-they-wrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After tinkering a bit, I found the following solution :

- Set the inner divs to `flex-shrink : 1` so they can shrink
- Set the p to `display : table-caption` (I didn't even know this existed)

```css
#container {
  width: 270px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px green solid;
}

div {
  border: 2px black solid;
  flex-shrink: 1;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-caption;
  
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <p>Small text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>This is another small paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not sure table-caption is a good idea here even if it will work

Comment: That's the only way I found. Everybody else says it's impossible or provide non working examples, so I guess it's better than nothing :)

Comment: the issue is that table-caption has a meaning and should be considered with table ... also impossible means that you need to understand why CSS is like that and reconsider the stuff ... for me this a logic behavior and not an issue and if he understand why it's like that we can easily do something else

Comment: @Temani Are you sure there is a problem of semantics ? He didn't use incorrectly a "table-caption" tag, he use a "p" tag and order it to **behave like** a "table-caption", so browsers still know that it is a paragraph. (BTW, thank you Jeremy Thille)

Comment: @Charles.C i will simply resume that this is more a hack than normal way :) since it's working and the properties are known there is no issue but i guess we shouldn't  always use them like that, but we can of course ;)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible since the `p` element, even if you set it to `display: inline-block` will take 100% of the parent width as soon as its text wraps (that is, if there is no `width` setting for it).  But trying around, i came up with a version that might work as a woraround for you. The essential thing about it is that there are inner and outer wrappers, a combination of `inline` and `inline-block` display and a `padding` in the outer wrapper. Maybe it helps you...

```css
#container {
  width: 270px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 2px green solid;
}

.outer_wrapper {
  border: 2px black solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}

.inner_wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: yellow;
}

p {
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="outer_wrapper">
    <div class="inner_wrapper">
      <p>Small text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="outer_wrapper">
    <div class="inner_wrapper">
      <p>This is another small paragraph</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I also thought so, but yes it is possible. See my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

in your style sheet, #container has a width:270px --- any reason you have a fixed width

i would suggest, remove it, if it is not needed or change it to 100% and display:block;

also you may want to style div element as -- div{width:50%;border: 2px black solid;}

Comment: Try and make a runnable code snippet to illustrate your point.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you want? I removed `flexbox` and went with `inline-block` display. Also remember that `p` tags automatically have a `margin` attached to them.

```css
#container {
  border: 2px green solid;
}

div {
  border: 2px black solid;
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "Times New Roman";
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <p>Small text</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <p>This is another small paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
```