# How to center a responsive flexbox div horzontally within an outer div

Tags: css, flexbox, centering

I have been trying to make a simple responsive flexbox layout in which columns wrap so that they always line up vertically.

That works fine:

```css
  .outer {
                margin: auto auto; /* Not centering contents of .inner div */
            }
            .inner {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap:wrap;

            }

            .inner .item {
                
                width: 205px; 
                height: 180px; 
                background: red; 
                margin: 10px; 
            }
            
            .item {
                
            }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
        <div class="item">9</div>
        <div class="item">10</div>
        <div class="item">11</div>
        <div class="item">12</div>
        <div class="item">13</div>
        <div class="item">14</div>
        <div class="item">15</div>
        <div class="item">16</div>
        <div class="item">17</div>
        <div class="item">18</div>
        <div class="item">19</div>
        <div class="item">20</div>
        <div class="item">21</div>
        <div class="item">22</div>
        <div class="item">23</div>
        <div class="item">24</div>
        <div class="item">25</div>
        <div class="item">26</div>
        <div class="item">27</div>
        <div class="item">28</div>
        <div class="item">29</div>
        <div class="item">30</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

... except that the whole outer div is aligned to the left. I want to keep the vertical alignment of the red item blocks as it is but center the whole output in the window.

I expected `display: block; margin: 0 auto;` on the outer div to achieve this but it doesn't. Any ideas?!

Comment: simply because there is nothing to center, your content is full width .. you can only center the flex items

Comment: So what to do? I tried adding `width`s to both the inner and outer divs but that doesn't work.

Comment: `justify-content:center` on the `inner`

Comment: You can also try with `.item { position: absolute; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); margin: auto; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; top: 0; }`

Comment: what you want is not possible, explained here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with the `justify-content:center` on the `inner` solution although it's not quite what I had pictured. I'll mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inner div is full width so maring auto won't work here. You can also add a `justify-content` on the inner div.

```css
  .outer {
            }
            .inner {
                display: flex;
                flex-wrap:wrap;
              justify-content: center;
            }

            .inner .item {
                
                width: 205px; 
                height: 180px; 
                background: red; 
                margin: 10px; 
            }
            
            .item {
                
            }
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
        <div class="item">5</div>
        <div class="item">6</div>
        <div class="item">7</div>
        <div class="item">8</div>
        <div class="item">9</div>
        <div class="item">10</div>
        <div class="item">11</div>
        <div class="item">12</div>
        <div class="item">13</div>
        <div class="item">14</div>
        <div class="item">15</div>
        <div class="item">16</div>
        <div class="item">17</div>
        <div class="item">18</div>
        <div class="item">19</div>
        <div class="item">20</div>
        <div class="item">21</div>
        <div class="item">22</div>
        <div class="item">23</div>
        <div class="item">24</div>
        <div class="item">25</div>
        <div class="item">26</div>
        <div class="item">27</div>
        <div class="item">28</div>
        <div class="item">29</div>
        <div class="item">30</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This will position all the elements directly in the inner div centered

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I want. With that layout the bottom row of divs does not line up: https://gyazo.com/eecce84b3416b93bf2ebda3a68703416  - I want it all centred with the red blocks all lining up vertically: https://gyazo.com/995d2343badaaca747aefadcb5169ec1