# Single row layout with multine line child which wraps to minimum width

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, css-grid

### Question

Can you produce such layout with CSS?

I want to have a single row with 2 children:

- Child A has multiple rows,
- Child B has a single one.

I want the the layout in which:

1. Child A accomodates on a single line as many children as possible for A and B to still fit on a single line.
2. Child A has the smallest width possible to achieve #1.
3. Child B then takes all the remaining space.

My HTML:

```
<div class="Container">
  <div class="ChildA">
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="ChildB">
    <button>
      Click me please
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My desired layout:

[image: Desired layout]

### Sketch of a solution using Flexbox

So far I came up with the following CSS using Flexbox:

```
.Container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  border: 4px solid black;
}

.ChildA {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: 4px solid red;
}

.ChildB {
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: auto;
  border: 4px solid blue;
}
```

It produces layout pictured below. The problem is it violates rule #2 - child A does not have the smallest width possible, but instead takes all the remaining space, which I want to be taken by child B instead.

[image: Layout I was able to produce]

### CSS Grid?

It seems the solution may be possible using CSS Grid (and it's `auto-fit` value), but I haven't been able to produce a fully working one myself yet. The closes I've come is [that pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjGWYy?editors=1100), which works fine on some window widths, but I cannot work out how to remove `max-width: 50vw` constraint.

### Note

I want a fully dynamic/flexible solution, which would work with content of any size in the containers.

Children content in my example are inputs and button, but that's just a random example - they can be `<div>`s or any other elements, if it makes the layout easier to implement.

### Fiddle

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mjdmXG?editors=1100

Comment: You cannot achieve this because : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width

Comment: But this answer relates specifically to `inline-block` display. That doesn't mean you can't achieve it with Flex or Grid. Especially that the last answer in that question posts a Grid solution. I'm trying to work how to port it to my situation...

Comment: and your elements are inline-block (input) that's why I said you cannot achieve it with what you have but this doesn't mean it's impossible at all ;)

Comment: But in my question I don't put any restrictions on what kind of `display` you set on the elements. So you can set some other `display` value on those inputs (actually they are just an example, the content could be anything else). I added a note about it in the question, so that it's clear.

Comment: in this case you have your answer in the link I shared ;) simply use grid for the A element and make the B element to fit the remaining space

Comment: Then if you post it as an answer, I'll accept it :).

Comment: well, working ont it ;) not easy as expected

Comment: I came up with [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bjGWYy?editors=1100) which works as desired on some page widths, but `max-width: 50vw` constraint makes it not working on others. I'm not sure how to remove it, but maybe it'll help you.