# Center a group of flex items and left-align them on wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I am triying to center a group of flex items and then, left-align them on wrap.This means I can't use *justify-content: center;* or *justify-content: space-between;*

[Image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4rvo.png)

As you can see in the image, the elements are not centered.

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container transp" style=" padding:2%">

    <div class="grid">
        <div class="cell">
            <a class="grid-item">
                <img src="http://www.nafpaktia.com/data/wallpapers/34/839687.png" >
            </a>
        </div>

         <div class="cell">
            <a class="grid-item">
                <img src="http://www.nafpaktia.com/data/wallpapers/34/839687.png" >
            </a>
        </div>

         <div class="cell">
            <a class="grid-item">
                <img src="http://www.nafpaktia.com/data/wallpapers/34/839687.png" >
            </a>
        </div>

         <div class="cell">
            <a class="grid-item">
                <img src="http://www.nafpaktia.com/data/wallpapers/34/839687.png" >
            </a>
        </div>

         <div class="cell">
            <a class="grid-item">
                <img src="http://www.nafpaktia.com/data/wallpapers/34/839687.png" >
            </a>
        </div>

         <div class="cell">
            <a class="grid-item">
                <img src="http://www.nafpaktia.com/data/wallpapers/34/839687.png" >
            </a>
        </div>

         <div class="cell">
            <a class="grid-item">
                <img src="http://www.nafpaktia.com/data/wallpapers/34/839687.png" >
            </a>
        </div>

         <div class="cell">
            <a class="grid-item">
                <img src="http://www.nafpaktia.com/data/wallpapers/34/839687.png" >
            </a>
        </div>

         <div class="cell">
            <a class="grid-item">
                <img src="http://www.nafpaktia.com/data/wallpapers/34/839687.png" >
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>




</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
box-sizing: border-box;
margin: 0;
}
.grid{

background-color:red;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1200px;
}
.cell{
  margin:0.5rem;
}

cell a{
display:block;
}
cell a img{
display:block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .grid {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;

  }
  .cell {
    width: 30%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1000px) {
  .cell {
    width: calc(100% / 6);
  }
}
img{
width:100%;
}
```

Pay attention to the part of @media screen and (min-width: 600px) as is the part where I'm using a flex display.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width