# Make CSS flexbox the width of its inner elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/54rp7x29/ I've set a flexbox to contain some fixed-width items. But the outer `container` element is wider than the items inside it. How can I set it to be no bigger than it needs to be? And to always be no bigger than it needs to be when the screen is resized (which will cause more or less flexbox items to be in the same row)?

This is the html:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the css:

```
html {
  max-width: 60%;
}

#content {
  background-color: green;
  height: 20px;
}

#container {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#container>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

#container>div>div {
  width: 80px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 3px;
}
```

Comment: `display:inline-block;` on container?

Comment: @TemaniAfif If I shrink the screen width causing flex items to wrap to the next row, then there's extra width on the container.

Comment: for this width you can do nothing ... check this to understand why and for some workaround : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thank you could you please update my jsfiddle using that workaround and I'll mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for ? here just i have removed the html tag from css.
if else please let me know

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
    #content {
        background-color: green;
        height: 20px; 
    }
    #container {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: yellow;
    }
    #container>div {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: center;
    }
    #container>div>div {
        width: 80px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: gray;
        margin: 3px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    </div> 
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: If I shrink the screen width causing flex items to wrap to the next row, then there's extra width on the container.

Comment: obviously when you are shrinking the screen size, you will get the extra space in the container. take for eg
if screen width is 200px and your item is 80px which you have hardcoded.
while shrinking the screen width to 170px then the extra space would be = 170%80 = 10px

Answer (score 0):

I thing you want to remove outside yellow space if you want please add **display: table;** on container.