# How do I get rid of extra space when the text is multi-line

Tags: html, css

I'm writting a badge-ish block.

The problem is with the 3<sup>rd</sup> block (`1 (Something something)`), as you can see in the snippet, it overflows to the next line and leaves extra space on the right.

[image: A picture of this problem same as described in the post]

What should I do to get rid of that space?

It would be tremendously great if it's pure CSS and doesn't involve jQuery.

Thanks!

---

```css
section {
  width: 8rem;
}

div {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.outer {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-height: 32px;
  min-width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="outer">
    1
  </div>

  <div class="outer">
    Very very very long Textttttt
  </div>

  <div class="outer">
    1 (Something something)
  </div>

  <div class="outer">
    Test
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: short answer, you cannot

Comment: @TemaniAfif You can! I wish you hadn't closed this.

Comment: @AndyHoffman how? if you know I can reopen it or you can add your answer to the duplicate. (I also know another duplicate, will try to find it)

Comment: @AndyHoffman you didn't remove the space, you simply added an extra element and hack this with a coloration (as a side note, you don't need the gradient, a simple color is fine)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think it would have solved this question, but am not in the mood to argue about it. Deleted.

Comment: @AndyHoffman no need to argue or to delete. I am simply justifying the duplicate closure. If you think it solves the issue then keep it and it's up to the OP and the community to decide (not me). If it solve the issue of the OP, the question can be edited to hightlight the fact that the space shouldn't be *really* deleted and that hacks are allowed to visually hide it. In this case, the question will be different and answers too (I will also add my own hack)

Comment: @TemaniAfif While I think my [re-added answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width#answer-54940883) better solves *this* closed question, maybe it will still help somebody.