# Flex items - inconsistent width

Tags: css, flexbox

I've got flex container with multiple items in it.  It's very simple - 100% width container with text element inside.  Text elements can be various width and need to all fit within the 100% width.  If the width is not enough, the individual elements may wrap as required. This works quite well.

Now, when there is enough width for all elements to fit without wrapping, there is equal white space between them. However when the elements shrink in width and text wraps, they don't seem to be correctly spaced any more.  It seems that the flex basis does not calculate correctly and as a result, those elements that wrap end up having a much larger white space on the right (it's an ltr container).

Here's the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0pnc6rwv/1/) and the relevant code:

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
<li>Longer item</li>
<li>Short</li>
<li>Even longer item</li>
<li>Another long item</li>
<li>And another one</li>
<li>Item6</li>
<li>Item 7</li>
<li>Average item</li>
<li>I need a few</li>
<li>This should be enough</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

All equal spacing when no wrap:
[image]

Uneven spacing when wrapping:
[image]

How can I get the spacing between items to always be equal regardless of the wrapping (or not) of individual items)?

Comment: You can't - that's just the way wrapping works inside a flex-child - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37406353/make-container-shrink-to-fit-child-elements-as-they-wrap

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width

Comment: It's not a `flex-basis` matter. It's about wrapping. See the links above.

Comment: Yeah, looked at those questions now.  Doesn't look promising.  My client says "I need it that way - it's your problem to solve".  Any ideas on how to approach it?

Comment: You could try the `auto-fill` / `auto-fit` functions of CSS Grid. That will solve the spacing issue. But it may require you to define column widths. https://jsfiddle.net/szcp0L5e/

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin It's not quite solving it.  The items wrap onto the next line - this is out of the question.  Also, fixed width columns are against what the client is asking.

Comment: Perhaps this? https://jsfiddle.net/ezx2f6ck/

Comment: Thanks, but, unfortunately, it doesn't do it - see here: https://jsfiddle.net/0mz6t3kr/ for what happens when I set text-align to left (as it needs to be).

Comment: Even with CSS-Grid you will get the same issue - it's the just the way text wraps - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/vYymvgm

Comment: Ok, I'll spend some time trying to do with with javascript... very annoying, indeed.

Comment: *My client says "I need it that way - it's your problem to solve".* - Explain that re-writing the way the internet works is a much bigger contract.

Comment: Go through [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37413580/3597276) in the first comment above. There are some JS solutions that may work for you.

Comment: text-align:center and your done

Answer (score -2):

You need to add this in your css. Add this **flex-wrap: wrap** inside your `<ul>` to be able to wrap the list, then you need to add a **min-width** inside your `<li>` so the gap of the list items will not shrink when you resize the browser.

Comment: You are missing the point: the list should _not_ wrap, only text within individual items.

Comment: You mean the items will not wrap but the the text will, to get the same equal gaps..? the only thing i can think of is to let the padding of the `<li>` bigger than **5px** then add a **word-break: break-all** so the text within the list will wrap. And the padding would be the gaps. I hope this is what your looking for.