# Align left content in flex container, css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container:

```
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <span class="breadcrumb-item  ">
      <a href="#">Reports</a>
    </span>
     <span class="breadcrumb-item  ">
      <a href="#">Some really really long name1</a>
    </span>
    <span class="breadcrumb-item  ">
      <a href="#">Some really long name2</a>
    </span>
    <span class="breadcrumb-item  ">
      <a href="#">Some really long name3</a>
    </span>
</div>
```

The styles:

```
.breadcrumb {
    margin-left: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 0.5rem;
}
```

Here's my [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/w6PDUaZ446UUgtC2?open=lib%2Fscript.js). I'd like to remove extra space between the items in flex container and align them left, currently for smaller screens it looks like this:

[image]

I'd appreciate any help!

Comment: They _are_ aligned to the left, same as they were on a wider viewport where they all still fit without anything breaking into multiple lines. Add `span { outline: 1px solid red; }` for debugging purposes, and you'll see that this extra space is actually contained _inside_ those spans. And that is actually a problem that can't be fixed easily - https://stackoverflow.com/q/34995740/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37406353/1427878

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting what you want to achieve, then you set both of these by yourself in the style.
Just change the gap and the margin-left to 0.
It would look something like this:

```
    .breadcrumb {
      margin-left: 0;
      display: flex;
      align-items: left;
      gap:0;
    }
```

The elements are aligned left by default.