# Aiming to remove extra spacing to the left/right of p tag when center aligned text runs over two lines

Tags: html, css

On my site, there is a utility bar with two messages - one on the left and one on the right. The text on both sides runs over two lines, and it is center aligned.

The problem I am having is this. I want the left-hand side of the message on the left to be aligned with the left-hand side of the parent container.

Unfortunately, when the text is center aligned, this space appears on the left and right hand side of the text. I want the p tag to shrink so that it takes up on the width of the text inside, but this doesn't appear to happen.

This is what my code looks like:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.utility-bar {
    padding-left: 64px;
    padding-right: 64px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.utility-bar__container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: initial;
    padding: 0;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.utility-bar p {
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="utility-bar">  
    <div class="utility-bar__container">
        <p>Text message to show what happens if text wraps</p>

        <p>Text message to show what happens if text wraps</p>
      </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: There isn't really a convenient way to achieve this, at most there are some hacks that can achieve this under some very specific conditions. https://stackoverflow.com/q/34995740/1427878, https://stackoverflow.com/q/450903/1427878