# CSS flex - have at least two items per row with minimal text truncation

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on a layout of items in CSS and I am trying to achieve the following:

- If there are enough items, then there should be at least two items or more per row. There could be more than two items to a row if they are narrow enough to fit on the same line.
- If the text in an item is too long to fit the remaining space, then the text should be truncated with an ellipsis and should not wrap to more than one line.
- The space should be utilized as efficiently as possible to try to fit as many items per row (thereby reducing the number of rows), while also minimizing the amount of truncation (and keeping at least two items or more on a row).

The main goals are to: have as many items per row as possible (at least two per row) while minimizing the amount of truncation that happens (so use as much space per row as necessary).

--

Given those requirements, I have been trying to use a flexbox for the layout, but I am having trouble getting there to be at least two items to a row (for that, I set the max-width to 50%, as shown below), while also allowing the items to fill the space if necessary, so as to avoid truncating the text.

The following example shows this.

[image]

In this example, there is extra space on the top row, after "Item Two...". That item should be, ideally, stretched to fill the space so the content is not as truncated as it is now.

On the second row, "Item Three..." could be stretched a bit more to reveal more of its text, while moving "Item Five" to the next row. "Item Four" has to stay on this row, however, due to the requirement of having at least two items per row.

But I am just trying to fit at least two items per row (or more if possible without truncating too much text), while displaying as much of each item as possible. I don't want a bunch of extra whitespace if that means some of the items are unnecessarily truncated.

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I could change or do here? I think one thing that I would need to get rid of is the max-width constraint, as that makes it so the items might be unnecessarily truncated. But if I remove that constraint, then the longer items will end up taking more of the line and could result in there only being one item per row, which is not good either.

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.box > * {
  flex: 0 1 max-content;
  max-width:calc(50% - 4px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}


/* Just for visual styling purposes */
.box {
  border: 2px dotted rgb(96, 139, 168);
  width: 300px;
}

.box > * {
  border: 2px solid rgb(96, 139, 168);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(96, 139, 168, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Item One</div>
  <div>Item Two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two</div>
  <div>Item Three has more content and so has a larger size</div>
  <div>Item Four</div>
  <div>Item Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, that's the way text-overflow and inline elements work. See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width

Comment: Frankly, `float` might be a better option here. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jOdewqX

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks so much for your comments. The float option looks good, but it still suffers from the max-width that I have set to be 50%. I have that there so I can have always at least two items per row. Other than that, I would like for the longer items to potentially stretch more than 50%. For example, if one item is naturally 20% of the container width, another item is 70%, and another item is 10%, then I would like all those to be on the same row with no truncation. If the items were 20%, 85%, 30%, 65%, then the items should be sized such that they are {20%, 80% (truncated)}, {30%, 65%}

Comment: This just isn't possible given your parameters. You have to sacrifice one of them to meet the others.

Comment: @Paulie_D Okay, yeah that is what I was afraid of. I was hoping there was something I was overlooking, but okay. I will probably end up calculating the widths of each element using JavaScript. Thanks so much for your help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like this work for you?

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 4px;
}

.box>* {
  flex: 1 1 150px;
  max-width: calc(50% - 4px);
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.box {
  border: 2px dotted rgb(96, 139, 168);
  padding: 4px;
  width: 100%;
}

.box>* {
  border: 2px solid rgb(96, 139, 168);
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(96, 139, 168, 0.2);
  padding: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div>Item One</div>
  <div>Item Two two two two two two two two two two two two two two two</div>
  <div>Item Three has more content and so has a larger size</div>
  <div>Item Four</div>
  <div>Item Five</div>
  <div>Six</div>
  <div>Seven</div>
  <div>Eight</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That's really good, but I am also trying to get it such that the items take the minimum amount of space necessary, so as many items per row can fit. For example, "Item One" would ideally be smaller so that more of "Item Two" could be shown without truncating it. And then the second row would have "Item Three" and "Item Four", with item four being as small as possible and item three stretching. Then the third row would have item five, six, seven, and eight (assuming they all could fit on the row), all sized minimally. I hope that makes sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: @ashipma is there any reason we can't use JavaScript to calculate the length of the content in each child div?

Comment: No, that's a possibility. I was just hoping this might be doable with just CSS. But JavaScript is an option too. I haven't really thought much about that approach yet, but I guess on resize I could go through each element and measure their max-content width and then also measure the width of the container and then one-by-one, apply a max-width (or maybe just a width) to each element such that the constraints mentioned in this question are satisfied. That could definitely work and I will probably work on doing that as the solution if there are no CSS-only solutions.

Comment: @ashipma I am currently working on a solution that will hopefully do what your asking but it's proving a bit difficult.

Comment: @ashipma I've officially lost my mind. If this is possible, It's gonna take someone a lot smarter than me haha.

Comment: No worries and thank you so very much for taking the time to look into this and for all your help. I truly appreciate your efforts.