# how to make the block width match the text width

Tags: css

My goal is to make the **.text** width the same as the text inside width. The correct **.text** width is obtained only when the text is on one line. **width: min-content** is not suitable. I'm interested in the text, the examples from StackOverflow with inline divs without text are not suitable for this example

Now:
[image]

Goal:
[image]

```css
.container {
  display: block;
}
.text {
  color: black;
  position: relative;
}
.text::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h2 class="text">
  texttexttexttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttexttexttextt exttexttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttext texttexttexttexttexttext
  </h2>
</div>
```

Here is sandbox https://jsfiddle.net/olegomel/32L5a640/10/

Comment: You can't, see: [CSS when inline-block elements line-break, parent wrapper does not fit new width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995740/css-when-inline-block-elements-line-break-parent-wrapper-does-not-fit-new-width)